# Correct procedure for git push using Tortoise Git

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Recently I did a git push, but it replaced changes done by other to the master.
Procedure I used:
-Right click on git folder on my machine
-Commit the changes
-Select TortoiseGit->Push

Comment: (TortoiseGit)Git does not overwrite changes by other automatically. Did you select "force" or one of the checkboxes behind it?

Comment: What do you mean replaced changes ? did you delete commits from the history (in which case : don't use force when you shouldn't) or did you just commit stuff that undid what they had done before ?

Comment: I didn't do a force push, I just did a Push. "force" might have been selected, i didn't notice it. So how should i make a push then?